# Understanding Stanford CoreNLP TokensRegex syntax for arbitrary phrase matching

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

So I've been working with NLP recently and I'm having trouble using their regex syntax for anything other than extremely simple matches like /test/. The end game I'm searching for is to match phrases that contain specific words somewhere in their contents. The speech patterns I'm trying to model are very structured but, because human speech is variable, the phrases could start a myriad of ways but as long as the phrase contains certain key words I want to count it. So as an example a regex I'm trying to model in TokensRegex is:

```
.*(show).*(cars).*(\d{0,9})(km|mi).*
```

which would match a phrase like:

`"please show me all cars within 100 km of me"`

Its not apparent to me from their documentation that a phrase that complex can be constructed. If it can I'm having trouble seeing how to convert it to their syntax. The closest I've come to what seems to match is this:

```
"[]*/(show)/[]*/(cars)/[]*[word>=0]/(kilometer|miles)/[]"
```

this a snip of the code I'm using to check for matches:

```
//value is the regex, tokens is the List<CoreLabel>s of text to try and match
pattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile(value);
TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(tokens);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String matchedString = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(matchedString);
    return true;
}
```

When I debug it I see the elements inside the matcher is a list of CoreLabels

```
(show,me,all,cars,within,a,hundred,kilometers,of,me)
```

and the pattern is compiled into a list of SequencePattern

```
 (*,TextAnnotation:/show/,*,TextAnnotation:/cars/,*,TextAnnotation GE 0.0, TextAnnotation:/(kilometer[s]?|mile[s]?)/,*)
```

To me that seems like it should match but it doesn't. Even something as stripped down as:

```
show me all cars
```

with the regex:

```
[]/show/[]/cars/[]
```

doesn't match so it makes me lean towards not setting up the regex right. Is there something I'm not understand about the limitations of TokensRegex or am I not constructing the expressions correctly. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't need TokensRegex directly for my problem. The key thing I was trying to solve was picking out numbers in a phrase and convert them but I realized that I could use CoreNLP's NERClassifierCombiner to pick them ouy,replace them, and use plain regular expressions to match the updated input phrase. Example of what I did is below, for phrases like "Show me all cars within fifteen kilometers" this converts it to "Show me all cars within 15 kilometers":

```
        Sentence sentence = new Sentence(eventName);
        String serializedClassifier = "english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
        NERClassifierCombiner combiner = null;
        try {
            combiner = new NERClassifierCombiner(serializedClassifier);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<String> reconstructedEventTokens = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CoreLabel cl : combiner.classify(sentence.asCoreLabels())) {
            if(cl.ner() == KBPRelationExtractor.NERTag.NUMBER.name){
                reconstructedEventTokens.add(cl.get(CoreAnnotations.NumericCompositeValueAnnotation.class).toString());
            }else{
                reconstructedEventTokens.add(cl.originalText());
            }
        }
        String newEvent = String.join(" ",reconstructedEventTokens);
        System.out.println("matching phrase to check: "+newEvent);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(value);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newEvent);
```

Took some more digging into the library to find the NER toolkit but its working like a charm now! Hope this helps someone else that's trying to find numbers or other entities in their phrases.